# magento 2 doesn't copying product picture in tmp folder

Tags: magento2, php

I creating a product pro grammatically in magento2. The issue is that i can't set addImageToMediaGallery. I always receive error:

> ***The file "/home/xxx/pub/media/tmp/catalog/product/t/e/test.jpg" doesn't exist or not a file***

My **picture locating in /pub/media/testimg/test.jpg**
media folder and has 777 permissions and files has same perms.
Here is a code:

```
$dir = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList');
$_product->addImageToMediaGallery(
    $dir->getPath('media') . '/testimg/test.jpg',
    null,
    false,
    false
);
```

so it looks like the system found the image but can't copy in tmp folder ? please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
sudo chmod -R 775 var/tmp/ pub/media/
```

Answer (score -1):

You will not change any template files , you can give permission in `pub/media` folder. You will get.

```
sudo chmod -R 777 var/ media/
```